# We've got a blog! Would you like to contribute to it?

Tags: discussion, blog

First off, [we've got a blog!](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/)

Would you like to contribute to it? You'll need to contact an administrator for an account. We need to know your username here on diy.stackexchange.com, and we'll need to know your email address -- or at least, the one you want to be associated with on the blog. Please specify if you'd like to be on the administrative crew (responsible for editing other people's posts and helping with the posting schedule), or would just like to contribute.

You can send this information to my email inbox by filling out [this form](http://www.karlkatzke.com/contact/); please label the subject something like "diy.stackexchange blog" so that it gets into my inbox. When I set up an account, you will receive an email with a password in it, and you will have access.

Blog contributors now have their [own chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1481/diy-blog-contributors). Please star it if you're planning on helping with the blog.

Comment: Great! e-mail sent.

Comment: Sent. Thanks Karl!